# css, external fonts

Tags: css, fonts

I have a big problem with css, how can I pun this font MyriadPro-It.otf in CSS?

Thanks !

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233/fonts-on-the-web http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718488/how-to-use-our-custom-font-on-our-website

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can add this css in your style sheet.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "MyriadPro";
        font-style: normal;
        src: url(../fonts/MyriadPro-It.eot); /*if IE */
        src: local("Grandesign Regular"), url("../fonts/MyriadPro-It.ttf") format("truetype"); /* non-IE */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this resource: [Mozilla CSS font face](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/beautiful-fonts-with-font-face/).

It's a guide that will help you get started. Also, check out [Google](http://www.google.com/), it's your friend. :)

Answer (score 1):

For your local machine, just install the font, and you should be able to access it with css (you might need quotes?).

If you want it to show up everywhere (which you probably meant with your question), then you better check out the dupes.